# Can I tell from the contents of a WM_DEVICECHANGE messages which device it corresponds to?

Tags: windows

My application needs to detect when a particular usb device is inserted/removed. This device exposes several interfaces (serial port, network adapter, among others). I can catch the WM_DEVICECHANGE message, but I don't see any data in the message itself that would uniquely identify my device (as opposed to say, somebody inserting/removing a usb-to-serial adapter). Am I missing something?

I know that I can do a WMI query whenever I get an event, to see if my device is there or not, but I was hoping there was a simpler/more elegant solution.

I have tried doing a WMI "event" query (rather than catching WM_DEVICECHANGE), but apparently my device does not support WMI events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for [DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in wParam of WM_DEVICECHANGE. At that point lParam will point to a [DEV_BROADCAST_HDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure which has more information.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thanks! I'd upvote, but I'm a newbie.